# Pycharm настройка: автозавершение кода (code completion)

Tags: pycharm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность отключить во всплывающей подсказке, когда нажимаешь `ctrl+space`, магические методы?

Они всегда эфир забивают, и, честно говоря, этим часто мешают видеть доступный интерфейс.